# Did Churchill say "Generals are always prepared to fight the last war"?

Tags: quotes, winston-churchill

I've seen the quote "Generals are always prepared to fight the last war" be attributed to Winston Churchill by [several](https://quotepark.com/quotes/1951878-winston-s-churchill-generals-are-always-prepared-to-fight-the-last-war/) [sources](https://quoters.info/quote/3429), but none of them actually give a primary source (such as a transcript of one of Churchill's speeches, a passage from one of his books, *et cetera*) to support this attribution.

Using Google Ngram, I've found that using the phrase "fighting the last war" in this context became popular for the first time around 1940, specifically as an explanation of the defeat of the Allied forces in the Low Countries and France against Germany that year. It's therefore not implausible that Churchill would have used it at some point, but I simply can't find any evidence of him ever doing so.

I think it's quite unlikely Churchill actually coined the phrase, but regardless, I'm interested in two questions: did this phrase actually originate with Churchill, and if it didn't, is it nevertheless possible to attribute the quote in the title to him?

Comment: Stack Exchange - History has a related (possibly duplicate) question [Who said, 'Armies prepare to fight their last war, rather than their next war' ?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/60422).

Comment: I have certainly seen similar quotes ascribed to Churchill, but I'm sure it would be hard to nail down.

Comment: @NigelJ Thanks for the link. One of the answers to that question cites a passage from *The Gathering Storm*, one of Churchill's books, in which Churchill says something that is vaguely similar to this quote. It's possible that the attribution of this adage to him is a consequence of that.

Comment: *"I think it's quite unlikely Churchill actually coined the phrase"* - Why do you think that?

Comment: "is it nevertheless possible to attribute the quote in the title to him?" is not on-topic for this site, since it gets into "proper writing/speaking style".  FWIW, I think that if you're directly quoting from some place that Churchill said/wrote the phrase then attributing it to him is the right thing to do (even if he wasn't the originator of the phrase).

Comment: @Dave I think you misunderstood my question. "Can we attribute this to him?" was intended to mean "did he actually say/write the phrase somewhere?"

Comment: @EgeErdil I have an attributution "1948 Winston S. Churchill _The Second World War_ I (Boston: Houghton Mifflin, 1985) 426: It is a joke in Britain to say that the War Office is always preparing for the
last war."  from http://listserv.linguistlist.org/pipermail/ads-l/2007-July/072054.html but I don't have a way to independently confirm that that quote occurs in that work.  If someone can, that would answer the "can it be attributed to WC?".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It has been said critically that there is a tendency in many armies to spend the peace time studying how to fight the last war.

- [January-February 1929, The Military Engineer, “Some Notes on the World War” by J. L. Schley (Lieutenant Colonel, Corps of Engineers), pg. 55, col. 1L](https://books.google.com/books?id=kPdKAQAAIAAJ&q=critically#search_anchor)

To me, this very closely captures the sentiment of Churchill's quote and pre-dates it (1920's vs. 1940's), and thus provides proof that Churchill did not originate the meme.  I found this via a [site maintained by Barry Popik](https://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/generals_always_fight_the_last_war).

Churchill himself wrote

> "It is a joke in Britain to say that the War Office is always preparing for the last war."

In Volume 1 (*[The Gathering Storm](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/360253.The_Gathering_Storm)*) of his [book series on WWII](https://www.goodreads.com/series/92939-the-second-world-war) first published in 1948; found on page 426 of the Mariner Books edition from 1985.

[image]

Comment: As the Q is posed, this A needs to confirm that in _Gathering Storm_ Churchill _does_ write this, and he does so as "on old joke" about the War Office… Lifting the very first Qcomment (https://history.stackexchange.com/q/60422) into the A would also be nice. (Usually, giving credit to the author of that comment, but on Skeptics, comments are different and _to be punished:_ by _not_ giving credit? IMO: Your choice.)

Comment: Accepting this answer for now. If anyone comes up with any evidence that Churchill actually said the quote in the title verbatim, I'm happy to accept that answer instead, but my current belief is that the quote I was wondering about is an altered version of the passage from *The Gathering Storm* provided in this answer.